# How to add vertical lines to ggplot boxplots in R

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, line, boxplot

I am plotting boxplots from this data:

```
MY_LABEL     MY_REAL     MY_CATEGORY
1 [POS]       .56            POS
1 [POS]       .57            POS
1 [POS]       .37            POS
2 [POS]       .51            POS
1 [sim v]     .65            sim v
...
```

I'm using ggplot2:

```
ggplot( data=myDF, aes( x=MY_LABEL, y=MY_REAL, fill=MY_CATEGORY ) ) +
    scale_colour_manual( values=palette ) +
    coord_flip() + 
    geom_boxplot( outlier.size = 0 )
```

This works fine, and groups the boxplots by the field `MY_CATEGORY`:
[image]

I'd like to do 2 things:

1) To improve the clarity of this plot, I'd like to add separators between the various blocks, i.e. between `POS` and `sim v`, between `sim v` and `C`, etc (see the ugly red lines in the plot).
I've been struggling with `geom_vline` with no luck.
Alternatively, I'd like to add blank space between the blocks.

2) If I print this plot in grayscale, I can't distinguish the different blocks. I'm trying to force a different palette with:

```
scale_colour_manual( values=c("black","darkgray","gray","white") )
```

Again, no luck, the plot doesn't change at all.

What would you suggest to do?

Comment: you should try playing around with facet_grid and facet_wrap. If you post a reproducible it is easier for us to help you.

Comment: I think you mean "horizontal" lines. Also, Eric is right: `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` are probably the best solution to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
require(ggplot2)
mtcars$cyl2<- ifelse(mtcars$cyl > 4, c('A'), c('B')) 
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot() + facet_grid(. ~ cyl2, scales = "free", space = "free")
```

would give something like this,
[image: bbb]

Answer (score 6):

No one covered the horizontal line route, so I thought I'd add it. Not sure why `geom_vline()` wasn't working for you. Here's what I did (chose to play off of Eric Fail's approach):

```
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p <- p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(cyl))) + coord_flip()
p <- p + geom_vline(xintercept=c(1.5,2.5))
p
```

There's only three boxplots here, but in playing around, ggplot appears to place them at integer locations. Just figure out which box you want a line after (nth) and put the xintercept argument at `n+0.5` for the line. You can obviously change the thickness and color to your liking: just add a `size=width` and `colour="name"` after the xintercept bit.

By the way, `geom_vline()` seems to work for me regardless of whether it's before or after `coord_flip()`. I find that counter-intuitive.

---

I'm not sure bdemarest is correct that you need the names to match the category names. I think the issue is that you used `scale_colour_manual()`, which applies if you used `aes(..., colour=var)` whereas you used `fill=var`. Thus, you need `scale_fill_manual`. Building on the above, we can add:

```
p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values=c("black","gray","white"))
p
```

Note that I've not defined any factor names for the colors to match. I think the colors are simply applied to your factor levels according to their order, but I could be wrong.

---

The end result of all of the above:

[image: cyl boxplot]

Comment: Is there any way to manually decrease the width of the boxplots so that they don't look so "fat"?

Comment: @baha-kev: Yes, though for some reason it doesn't seem to be documented? I was able to do `p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(cyl)), width=0.5) + coord_flip()`. Replace 0.5 with whatever you want. It's mentioned at [stat_boxplot](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/stat_boxplot.html), but not [geom_boxplot](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_boxplot.html).

Answer (score 1):

To change the fill colors, you need a named vector of values. The names need exactly match the y-axis category names.

```
scale_fill_manual(values=c("POS"="black", "sim v"="gray50",
                           "C"="gray80", "sim t"="white"))
```

To separate the y-axis categories, try `facet_grid()`.

```
facet_grid(factor(MY_CATEGORY) ~ ., drop=TRUE)
```

I'm not sure that this will work because I don't have your data to test it.